Angular PrimgeNg Table reset table with default sort
When I use table.reset() on p-table, all filters reset, and sorting disappears despite the default sort being set for the table:
<p-table [sortField]="defaultSortField" [sortOrder]="defaultSortOrder">

How can I achieve the following functions (separated)?

Apply the default sort field and sort order to the table.
Reset the filters while keeping the current sorting applied.

Thanks a lot for your help.
